# IOS 6 - Contacts have disappeared then when I type it in they re-appear temporally

Tags: icloud, contacts, ios, iphone

I recently updated my 3Gs to the new iOS 6. However after doing this I've noticed that a lot of my contacts are gone.

However if they call me or I type the number in, they pop up and will stay in my *recents* tab, but if I then go back into contacts they are still not there!

How is this possible? And more importantly, how can I get all my contacts back?

Comment: Does the title of the screen in the Contacts app read "All Contacts", or just "Contacts"? You may have inadvertently filtered out some groups (Tap the Groups button in the upper-left corner of the Contacts list and ensure All Contacts is checked).

Comment: No, tried that already Dan J, but no matter what display I try they wont re-appear